# Can you get the error-correction level of a QR code?

Tags: encodings, development

You can get the version number of a QR (1-40) by checking the dimensions of the QR, but is there a way to get the error-correction level that was used to generate the QR code?

Trying to reverse engineer a QR code, but I don't have access to the code that generated it, and I'd like to match the error-correction level.

Answer (score 2):

There is another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49287808) over at StackOverflow that answers this very nicely. There is an even better [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1050416) over at SuperUser that includes a picture.

In the end, they both point to the same [source](https://blog.qrstuff.com/general/qr-code-error-correction) that has a picture showing how you can tell how much error correction has been enabled for the QR code:

> There's also 2 modules down in the bottom left-hand corner of every QR
> code that display what the error correction level used in that QR code
> is.

Answer (score 1):

The specification for QR codes was easily findable on the internet the last time I checked. The redundancy level is encoded in the first two pixels below the top left alignment marker, and as redundant copy in the two bottom-most pixels in the column immediately past the bottom left alignment marker.